# Can I make pdb start debugging right away?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I want to debug a python project

The problem is, I don't know where to set a break point,

what I want to do, is be able to call a method

```
SomeClass( some_ctor_arguments ).some_method()`
```

and have the debugger be fired right away

How do I do that?

I tried `pdb.run( string_command )` but it doesn't seem to work right

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import <some-package>
>>> pdb.run( .... )
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
NameError: "name '<some-package>' is not defined"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it ..

```
pdb.runcall( object.method )
```

Comment: you can also start pdb from the command line to make it run before anything in your script.

python -m pdb yourscript.py

Answer (score 4):

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

will start the debugger at this point.

Place it at the beginning of the method you want to debug.